# android - xml - include same layout multiple times does not work

Tags: android, xml, layout, include

I'm trying to include the following layout twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

like the following

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/view_pager" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/view_pager" />
```

Actually, the second view pager does not work if I do it like that... The second view pager always stays empty... If I copy my view_pager layout and change the ids in this layout (pager to pager2 and indicator to indicator2) everything works fine. Is there a better way to do that? Copying layouts to achieve that seems to make the include useless for multiple includes of the same layout....

I'm getting the references correctly I think, but though it just does not work if I include the same layout...

```
pager1= (ViewPager)(findViewById(R.id.include1).findViewById(R.id.pager));
pager2= (ViewPager)(findViewById(R.id.include2).findViewById(R.id.pager));
```

Everything works perfectly if I copy the layout...

**Edit:**

I think it has to do with the FragmentManager, because the view pagers have the same id... But I don't know how to solve that correctly...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done. You can inflate the layout many times, but you have to make the inclusion programmatically. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917040/2651329) to same kind of question.