# Layout as a subset of another layout in android

Tags: android, html, xml, user-interface

I built a layout like this in XML say "block.xml"
[image: block.xml]

Now, i want to create an XML like this [image]

so that i can access each block as an array. Can somebody tell me how can i use block.xml as a template to generate my new xml file to be put as a UI part in android. Thank You

Just to be sure , i want to use table layout i dont know how to procees.

Comment: Have you looked at the <include> tag? http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html
Or a gridview with an adapter.

Comment: i think your need will match a layout inflater in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout xml you may use the include tag and re-use your block.xml
as:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/block1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        layout="@layout/block" />
```

And in your java code you can access views from block.xml as

```
View firstBlock = findViewById( R.id.block1 );
View blockButton = firstBlock.findViewById( R.id.someButtonId );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer .. . i need to know suppose if in the layout which i am using inside include tag, i want to access some of the items defined that xml. ..  can i do it? It would be very helpful

Comment: @Prakhar yes you can do it. Suppose you have a button view inside your block.xml u can access it in your java code, you need to give an  id to your incude tag in that case:    View firstBlock = findViewById( R.id.block1 ); // this is your inclide tag id
View blockButton = firstBlock.findViewById( R.id.someButtonId ); // this is your button view id inside the block.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should inflate and add the sub layouts programmatically.

This link has example code:
[Android using layouts as a template for creating multiple layout instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916527/android-using-layouts-as-a-template-for-creating-multiple-layout-instances/7917040#7917040)